# Getting the right format for saving multiselect customer attribute issue?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, multiselect

This is my code:

```
        $values = ['value1','value2','value3'];
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('customer_attribute_code', $values);
        //\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

`customer_attribute_code` is a custom customer multiselect attribute.  I'm trying to save all values from my arrray (`$values`), but it only save the first value: `value1`

Do you have any idea why ? I've also tried this format:

```
     $values[0] = 'value1';
     $values[1] = 'value2';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By changing the code into this:

```
$customer->setCustomAttribute('customer_attribute_code','value1,value2');
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

I've managed to save the custom customer multiselect attribute values